# Virtualize/Emulate/Catch-All PHP files in /templates directory

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Our project has around 15+ exactly equal data table index pages which show the content of a database table and provide the *Edit/Delete/Add* functionality.

I can put lot of the equal code into a PHP file which is then *included* by each `index.php` in the corresponding directory. Even this would minimize a lot of repeated code I am wondering if there is a possibility to make it more general.

My intention is that these `index.php` files do **NOT** exist and when they are accessed with `www.example.com/users` | `www.example.com/data1` | `www.example.com/data2` and so on, a *hook* delivers the content of the personalized HTML file on the fly. Which table is accessed is described in the URL - this is just a simple parse task.

**My question:**
Is there some of the described functionality? It would be some kind of a `catch-all` functionality for certain pages.

**Note**: More or less it should work like PhpMyAdmin. The PMA *engine*  displays standardized a table/database provided in the URL. BUT, of course, I am not writing another PMA, it's just an example how I expect it to work.

I am working with CakePHP 4.1.0

Comment: You could add a custom route that intercepts the `index` URLs and sends them all to a common controller action.

Comment: @GregSchmidt OK, but do I need the *Controller PHP files for each table or how would it work? Or must be there at least one Contoller file which _catches_ all of these request? Could you provide more details? I started with CakePHP 4.1 last week. I am a bloody beginner.

Comment: The way I'm picturing it, it would be just one controller that all such requests are sent to. The code for handling the request has to be *somewhere*, so you need at least one controller with one action to handle it. I have never done something like this, so don't have much more in the way of details. I guess I'd start with a simple controller and no custom routing and default the table name, then when that's working I'd look up routing documentation for how to get other URLs to get sent there, and how to pass the table name in.

Comment: @GregSchmidt In the CakePHP forum I was told to use this: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud I am checking it out but I think I should use this as it apparently covers all my needs. Thx